# Installing MS Visio 2010 and updates in PlayOnLinux/Wine

Tags: wine, playonlinux, visio

How do I install MS Visio 2010, updates and the Compatibility Pack on PlayOnLinux? There is a script in POL for Visio 2010 initial install, but not for the updates and the Visio Compatibility Pack so it would be good to have end-to-end directions.

Through trial and error, I can get up to installing the Visio Compatibility Pack, which opens files in Microsoft Visio 2010 that were created in the newer Visio drawing file format. I did this by changing the Wine Windows version to Win 7. I could not get the Visio Compatibility Pack to work.

When opening a vsdx file, it fails with the error message:

```
An error (1502) has occurred during the action Open File. Fine not found.
```

[image]

I am not sure if the issue is with the Visio Compatibility Pack install or with some setting changes I made somewhere earlier during trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Viseo 2010 Compatibility Pack is not working through Wine - the compatibility report on the Crossover website (a product based on Wine) indicate that it will install but it won't run.

https://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/crossover/microsoft-visio-2010-compatibility-pack

Since Crossover is geared toward better MS Office compatibility over regular Wine, and it won't run on Crossover, I'm certain it will be the same case with Wine itself.